# Why does git rm -rf not get rid of a folder with a submodule in it?

Tags: git

When I do `git status` this is what I see:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'github/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   octopress (modified content, untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I do `git rm -rf octopress`, this is what I see:

```
$ git rm -rf octopress
error: submodule 'octopress' (or one of its nested submodules) uses a .git directory
(use 'rm -rf' if you really want to remove it including all of its history)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

This error message confused me too, but what it is trying to say is that you should use `rm -rf`, **not** `git rm -rf`:

```
(use 'rm -rf' if you really want to remove it including all of its history)
```

So, you should be able to do this:

```
$ rm -rf octopress
$ git rm octopress
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are plainly after a clean output from git status, you could simply,

```
git status --ignore-submodules
```

Otherwise you will need to explicitly deal with the submodule. And before we deal with the submodule, note that  git submodules are not supposed to have a `.git` directory<sup>1</sup>. Could you be using an old version of git?

Moving on. Git tells you for the `octopress` submodule that it is,

```
#   modified:   octopress (modified content, untracked content)
```

To resolve this you would need to go into the `octopress` submodule and,

- Reset or commit the modified content
- Commit, delete or `.gitignore` the untracked content

Alternatively, using a bigger hammer, as you seem to suggest in the question, you can remove the local checkout of the submodule,

```
$ git submodule deinit --force octopress
```

<sub>Applicable from git 1.8.3 and onwards</sub>

When `--force` is specified, the submodule's work tree will be removed even if it contains local modifications.

Follow this by `git rm octopress` to remove the submodule from the repo.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Look at this patch,</sub>

> Move git-dir for submodules into $GIT_DIR/modules/[name_of_submodule] of 
>   the superproject. This is a step towards being able to delete submodule 
>   directories without loosing the information from their .git directory 
>   as that is now stored outside the submodules work tree. 
>   
>   http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v5-0-2-submodule-move-gitdir-into-superproject-td6692559.html